# In R how do i change the binwidth on my graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-science

```
ggplot(missense2)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=Variant.start.in.translation..aa.),stat="count")+
  theme_classic()+
  xlab("amino acid position")+
```

What do I add or use to allow the binwidth of the graph to be changed?

```
ggplot(missense2)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=Variant.start.in.translation..aa.),stat="count")+
  theme_classic()+
  xlab("amino acid position")+
```

The command (`binwidth= "2"`) altered nothing no matter where placed in the code.

Comment: With `geom_bar` there is no binning, hence no `binwidth`. Binning is a part of building a histogram so you'll find a `binwidth` argument in `geom_histogram`.  There is an answer now that demonstrates the properly named `width` argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameter `width`

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl))+
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl))+
  geom_bar(width = .5)
```

[image]